# Position CATextLayers along Arc

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform, catextlayer

I am trying to build a custom control which might look something like this Inkscape mockup:

[image]

I was doing things with `drawRect()` but I need to animate some of the elements, so I decided to switch to a composition of `CALayer`s. I had been drawing the text using `CGContextRef` functions, but having switched to `CATextLayer` for each character, I cannot seem to get them transformed correctly.

My general approach was to create a `CATextLayer` for each character. I *think* I can use each layer's `preferredFrameSize()` to get the eventual size of the character. And then I thought I would adjust their position and rotation in my control's `layoutSubviews()` method.

"What have I tried?" I feel like I've just been sitting on a sit-n-spin, blindfolded, throwing darts. You name it, I've tried it.

I can determine the angle of rotation for each character with something like:

```
let baseline = (self.ringBox.width * 3 / 8) // radius out to the baseline arc
let circumference = baseline * Tau
var advance = wordWidth.half.negated // wordWidth was summed from the width of each character earlier
let angle = 0.75.rotations
for each in self.autoCharacters {
    let charSize = each.bounds.size
    advance += charSize.width.half
    let charRotation = (advance / circumference - 0.75).rotations + angle
    ...
}
```

I've noticed that `layoutSubviews()` seems to be called twice. Why? I've noticed that the second time through, the `preferredFrameSize()` seems to be thinner. Why? Was it because I was setting the `affineTransform` and it had cumulative effects. I was trying to initially set the position of the layer to the center of the parent box, as well as bounds to be preferredFrameSize, hoping that would center it in the center. And then apply transforms. Despite multiple attempts, I get weird placement, as well as weird clipping.

So I'm just looking for a simple/straightforward recipe that will position a `CATextLayer` at a given radius/angle from the center of a view.

Comment: I've done a similar UI in the past.  Text around a circle, either inside or outside, and both clockwise and counter clockwise on the same circle.  I had the best success with drawing things in a drawRect method using TextKit to get glyphs and their rects directly.  I recall it just taking a lot of fiddling to get it correct.  Are you making your calculations based on the center of the baseline of each glyph?  That was a stumbling point for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I wrote a separate app with sliders for all of:

- frame origin
- frame size
- bounds origin
- bounds size
- position
- anchorPoint
- pre rotation transform translation
- transform rotation
- post rotation transform translation

As well as some debug info that showed the `preferredFrameSize()` of the layer. Armed with that, able to manipulate things and see the effects, I was able to actually get it down pretty simple.

After creating a single `CATextLayer` for each character in a given word (typed as `[CATextLayer]`), I used the following method to position the characters of the word:

```
// pass 1 to:
// - baseline each characters rotation
// - size it and center it
// - accumulate the length of the whole word
var wordWidth:CGFloat = 0.0
for letter in word {
    // baseline the transform first, because preferredFrameSize() is affected by any latent rotation in the current transform
    letter.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformIdentity)
    // the preferredFrameSize will now be the un rotated size of the single character
    let size = letter.preferredFrameSize()
    // move the letter to the center of the view
    letter.frame = CGRect(origin: center - size.half, size: size)
    // accumulate the length of the word as the length of characters
    wordWidth += size.width
}
let Tau = CGFloat(M_PI * 2)
// the length of the circle we want to be relative to
let circumference = radius * Tau
// back up the "advance" to half of the word width
var advance = wordWidth.half.negated
for letter in word {
    // retrieve the character dimensions
    let charSize = letter.bounds.size
    // advance half of the character, so we're at its center
    advance += charSize.width.half
    // determine the angle to rotate off of the nominal (which is 270 degrees)
    let charRotation = (advance / circumference * Tau - (Tau * 3 / 4)) + angle
    // start with an identity transform now
    var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    // rotate it. this will rotate about the center of the character
    transform = transform.rotated(charRotation)
    // translate outwards to the ring
    transform = transform.translated(CGPoint(x: 0, y: radius.negated))
    // apply the transform
    letter.setAffineTransform(transform)
    // move the advance the other half of this character
    advance += charSize.width.half
}
```